# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /root/AddUsers.php on line 158

Tags: php

I have added the following code to a php script that adds users to an LDAP directory, now we need to log the changes. but when I run the code I get the error in the title.

```
$myFile = "newuser.log";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$userInfo = $newUser['lastname'], $newUser['firstname'], $newUs$
fwrite($fh, $userInfo);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: So what is $userInfo = $newUser['lastname'], $newUser['firstname'], $newUs$ supposed to do? It isn't valid PHP syntax

Comment: Is it supposed to concat strings? That's a dot, not a comma. You are also missing the semicolon from the end.

Comment: This is not a question that is of general interest to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit, as far as I can see (since I don't see line numbers) is:

```
$userInfo = $newUser['lastname'], $newUser['firstname'], $newUs$
```

If you want to concatenate your array keys into one single variable, you have to use the "." operator. So it would be:

```
$userInfo = $newUser['lastname']  . ', ' . $newUser['firstname'] . ', ' . $newUs;
```

Also, you might want to check the end of that line (`$newUs$`) since that will end up in another syntax error (both `$`'s and the missing `;`)

Comment: That worked! Now, how could a use a tab to form rather than a , in the  string?

Comment: As far as I know, you would use . "\t " . (notice the use of double quotes). It *should* work.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing about this line makes any sense:

```
$userInfo = $newUser['lastname'], $newUser['firstname'], $newUs$
```

Are you trying to create an array? That last `$newUs$` wouldn't work even if you had used `array(...)`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know php worth anything, I am wanting $userInfo to be a string, and $newUser is an array that was made earlier in the script. and that is only part of that line the whole line is:

    $userInfo = $newUser['lastname'], $newUser['firstname'], $['uid'], $newUser['enteredby'], strftime('%c');

the way I copped the time from my terminal cut off part of it and I didn't not realize this